# AWK subtract numeric record two from record one

Tags: awk, fortran

I cannot solve a very simple problem. My data file looks like:

```
Crap Crap 0.123456789D+09 Crap Crap
Crap Crap 0.123456798D+09 Crap Crap
```

I need to use AWK to subtract the number in the third column; the SECOND row minus the FIRST row.

I tried:

```
cat crap.txt | awk '{ A[NR-1] = $3 } END { print A[1] - A[0] }'
```

to no success. Maybe the format of the number is wrong? (Can AWK read scientific notation with `D` instead of `E`?)

Help!

**EDIT:**

Just so the community knows, AWK does not understand scientific notation which uses `D` instead of `E` (like many Fortran outputs produce). It is necessary to replace the `D` for `E` and then carry on any mathematical operation.

Comment: Useless use of `cat`, by the way (other than "cat crap" being funny).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the notation on the fly...

```
cat crap.txt | awk '{ sub(/D/,"E",$3); A[NR-1] = $3; } END { print A[1] - A[0] }'
```

Comment: lose the cat and pass the file name to awk directly

Answer (score 1):

`awk` cannot read D-notation (what does it mean by the way?). Here is an example:

```
printf "1.2D+1\n1.2E+1\n12\n" | awk '{ print $1/3; }'
0.4
4
4
```

The first one is wrong.

Comment: In Fortran the D notation denotes a real number in double precision. So it is the same as `E` for all practical purposes. By the way, Python cannot read it either!